# Enabling / Disabling BroadcastReceivers

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, boot

I have a broadcast receiver that starts a service when the device is finished booting. However I don't know how to disable/enable it in code.

Here is my Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
      <intent-filter> 
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON">
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

BootReceiver.java:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    context.startService(new Intent(context, TouchService.class));
   }    
}
```

My question is, what do I put here?

```
if (!rBoot.isChecked()) {
   ????????????
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is use `SharedPreference` and set a `flag` when your device completes boot and check the flag for enabling and disabling your `BroadCastReceiver`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
boolean enabled=prefs.getBoolean(key, false);
int flag=(enabled ?
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED :
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED);
ComponentName component=new ComponentName(EditPreferences.this, OnBootReceiver.class);

getPackageManager()
    .setComponentEnabledSetting(component, flag,
                                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```